How to format efibootmgr command to make EFI stub entry for LVM root?
My current partitions and filesystems are as follows

/dev/nvme0n1 GPT
/dev/nvme0n1p1 EFI FAT32 mounted /mnt/boot ;
/dev/nvme0n1p2 SWAP ;
/dev/nvme0n1p3 ->

VolGroup0-lv_root ext4 mounted /mnt,
VolGroup0-lv_home ext4



Using the Arch wiki example my best guess is currently:
efibootmgr -c \
           -d /dev/nvme0n1 -p 1 \
           -L "Arch Linux" \
           -l /vmlinuz-linux \
           -u 'root=UUID=(lv_root volume) resume=UUID=(swap partition) rootflags=rw loglevel=3 quiet initrd=\initramfs-linux.img'

Trying this boot entry and restarting results in an error:
unable to mount UUID real root


Does the same system already have another working bootloader, or are you directly going for efistub bootloader for the initial installation?
